# I've published a wrong version number to VSCode marketplace. Best way to handle/downgrade version number?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

While doing a minor release (0.8.0), by mistake I've published a major version release (8.0.0).

I've contacted VSCode Marketplace but once a version is published they cannot remove it.

What is the best way to gracefully remove this version without affecting the 600 current users?

I'm thinking about deleting the extension and republishing it but I'm not sure about the effects on those with the 'latest' version installed.

I would like to keep the version number under 0.9.0 as this is still an unfinished product.

Comment: just live with the error and continue numbering from `8.0.0`, starting a new extension really would annoy 600+ users, use `vsce` possibility to increment major/minor version numbers

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going to publish updates to both 8.0.x and 0.8.x series for one month with this warning embeded:

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const extensionId = '';
    const version = vscode.extensions.getExtension(extensionId).packageJSON.version;
    const [mayor, minor, patch] = version.split('.');
    if (mayor > 0 && new Date() > new Date('2021-10-27')) {
        vscode.window
            .showErrorMessage(
                `${extensionId}: Due to an error in version numbers this version v${version} is no longer supported and it will not receive updates.
                Please use marketplace extension page to manually downgrade to series v0.9.x or 1.0.x`,
                'Open Marketplace Extension Page'
            )
            .then(result => {
                if (result === 'Open Marketplace Extension Page') {
                    vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', vscode.Uri.parse(`vscode:extension/${extensionId}`));
                }
            });
    }
```

This will give current user enough time to get automatic updates for series 8.0.x and one day before that date I will **delete extension and republish with same extensionId** so current 8.0.x users will be promted to manually downgrade and join 0.9.x series automatic updates and new users will get only 0.9.x series

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is currently planning a way to allow users to unpublish specific versions of their extension. The current proposal allows unpublishing (though you cannot reuse the same version number again after unpublishing it) See VS Marketplace PR [Create Unpublish specific version - Solution proposal.md #875](https://github.com/microsoft/vsmarketplace/pull/875).

So sit tight. I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".